# How to select a variable from an AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following response from an AJAX request (as per Chrome console):

```
`XMLHttpRequest {
statusText: "Not Found", 
status: 404, 
responseURL: "XXX", 
response: "{"apiVersion":"2.1","error":{"code":404,"message":…dException","internalReason":"User not found"}]}}", responseType: ""…`}
```

How can I select both the value of `statusText` and the `internalReason`?

When I try to set `var msg = response.data.statusText;` I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusText' of undefined`

Edit: Here's the code in context:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: yt_url,
    dataType:"json",

    success: function(response)
    {
    // code
    }
    error: function(response)
    {
    handleError(response);
    }
 });


function handleError(response) {
    var msg = response.data.statusText;
    $('#status').html('An error occurred:' + msg);
}
```

Comment: you cat test here your json if it is valid: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the data in a string. If you want to access it like an object, then you have to convert it into one.

You need to find, or write, a parser for whatever data format the data is in.

It looks like it is JSON, so you can use [`JSON.parse(string)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: It might have been parsed and stored somewhere else, but `response` is clearly shown in the output you quoted as a string. Presumably jQuery doesn't parse the bodies of 404 responses.

Comment: I have updated the question to explain the context - does this help?

Answer (score 0):

If your `json` is valid object then you should access like:

```
var msg = response.statusText // not response.data.statusText as there is not key as data
```